# Jest --findRelatedTests project structure/naming conventions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

[A similar question was asked back in May of last year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066996/how-does-jest-findrelatedtests-work-under-the-hood) but unfortunately didn't get any responses so I'd like to expand on it with some details of my own and hopefully gain some understanding of how `--findRelatedTests` works, because there doesn't seem to be any documentation that describes *how* it works, just that it *does*.

In short, what criteria needs to be in place for this for `--findRelatedTests` to work properly?

- Do the source file/test file need to be similarly named?

  e.g. `Page.jsx` and `Page.test.js`
- Do the test files need to be in the same folder as the source file, or should they be placed in a separate tests folder?

I ask because I tend to follow the AirBnb project structure for my applications:

```
- components
  - Page
    - index.jsx
    - style.scss
    - Page.test.js
```

...and I'd like to know if I updated the Page component `index.jsx` file whether `--findRelatedTests` would "know" that `Page.test.js` is the associated test file?

Comment: I did some digging and came up with an answer to the linked question, since that is higher voted and appears higher in Google. If I don't get accepted there in a while I'll repost here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51502218/5213573